# Failed Mysqli query in login php script : cannot successfully login

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I have this PhP script called `checklogin.php` which is supposed to query 'Email'  and 'motdepasse' values from a table called 'membres' (not members), the variables type are `varchar (50)` for Email and `char (120)` for motdepasse.

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">

    <title> Welcome to Pop </title>
    <link href="normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

<form  action = "checklogin.php"  method="post" name="login_form">
<section class="loginform cf">
<ul>
    <li><label for="usermail">Email</label> <input name="usermail" placeholder="yourname@email.com" required="" type="email" /></li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li><label for="password">Password</label> <input name="password" placeholder="password" required="" type="password" /></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
<input   type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"  />

<ul>
</ul>

<p><a accesskey="N" href="Newaccount.html" title="Redirecting ">Create an account</a></p>
</section>
</form>





</body>
</html>
```

checklogin.php :

```
<?php 
session_start();
$link = new MySQLi("localhost", "DBusername", "DBpassword", "DBname") ;
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if ( mysqli_connect_error() )
{

    $logmessage = 'MySQL error : ' . mysqli_connect_error() ; 
    die('could not connect to database');
}

$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Password = $_POST['Password'];
$query= "SELECT Email, motdepasse FROM membres WHERE Email='".$Email."' AND motdepasse='".$Password."' LIMIT 1 ";



if ($result = mysqli_query($link,$query )) 
{

    if( mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1 )
    {

        echo "login successful" ;
     }

     else
     {
          echo "wrong username or password" ;

     }
} 
else
{
    echo' Couldnt select from table. Please check query';
}
?>
```

My problem is that even though the connection to the DB is made without any problem whatsoever, I get the wrong username/password message even when information typed are matching the ones in 'membres' , Email and motdepasse columns. I since added error report function but only get notices.

Comment: What notices are you getting?

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text!**

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Security is **hard**.  Do not reinvent the wheel.  You should use an existing, proven, authentication system.

Comment: I get the following notices : undefined Index : Email and Pasword and then the locaions of the script, but I know how to fix these using Isset() as for SQL vulnerability, I plan to implement it later

Comment: @SLaks I hear there are god authentication systems out there, but I really want to keep my HTML page as it is part of a project, which is an option platform like Laravel don't let me use, if you know any good ones ill be glad to try them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML there are inputs named `usermail` and `password` but in your PHP code you are trying to get `$_POST['Email']` and `$_POST['Password']`. So just change that two lines to this:

```
$Email = $_POST['usermail'];
$Password = $_POST['password'];
```

Comment: thank you very much, that really helped and I can't believe I didnt notice it earlier. Upvote and marked as answer (trust me I did but rep ain't high enough for it to show)

Comment: Funny thing is , even though the notices are gone I still can't get the Login success message with the right info

Comment: If you echo `$query` just after initializing it, is that string alright? With filled credentials? Maybe try copy this SQL statement and run it in your MySQL editor (PhpMyAdmin or whatever else you are using).

Comment: I'll try it, thank you! if you're interested i'll let you know how that works out !

Comment: when I echo $query and the wrong username message I get : "wrong E-mail or password " followed by" SELECT Email, motdepasse FROM membres WHERE Email='correctemail@something.com' AND motdepasse='correectpassword' LIMIT 1" what do you tink?

Answer (score 0):

you send data from form like

```
<input name="usermail" ...
```

so the variable is `usermail` but in your script you handle `$_POST['Email']` and it really does not exist... first check your names of your form elements and debug what you sent via top line

```
var_dump($_POST); exit();
```

tip: always test what you have with what you expect and compare